# Understanding migration script

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, truffle

Let say I successfully deployed contract.sol using migration script  2_deploy_contract.js . Later contract has changes, What should I do?

1. Do changes in contract.sol and re-run truffle migrate ?
2. Not modify contract.sol, instead clone new file contract2.sol and 3_deploy_contract2.js and run migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on explanation what truffle migrarions are actually is:

> Migrations contract stores the number of the last deployment script
>   applied.  Truffle will not run those scripts again. On the other hand,
>   in the future, your app may need to have a modified, or new, contract
>   deployed. For that to happen, you create a new script with an
>   increased number that describes the steps that need to take place.
>   Then, again, after they have run once, they will not run again.

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/what-are-truffle-migrations

I would say that after you change something you have to write the new migration.

Comment: I should do option 2 that I mentioned in my post?

Comment: Not actually. You need to modify your contract.sol but create a new JS file with increased version number as far as I understand.